# Run program without any thing installed?

Tags: windows, windows-installer

Recently I have been making many useful programs, And I wanted to share these with my friends but in order to do that I first need to install that programming language on their computer. so I have been wondering that how could I code programs that don't require me to install something else.
meaning in order to run that program you only need to run a setup once and then you can use that program.

Comment: Hi and welcome. What kind of programm / code / application do you want to share? Is it C#?

Comment: You cannot install a programming language. Likewise, you cannot install an application and not install anything at the same time.